react prop is not working properly due to useState
This is the page from where i am sending the prop
  const [username, setusername] = useState(null);
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      await fetch("http://localhost:3000/logout", {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
      });

      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        credentials: "include",
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        setusername(data.username);
      } else {
        console.error("Login failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("An error occurred during login", error);
    }
  };

return (
    <>
      <Home username={username} />
      <Main username={username} />
    </>
}

This is my Main component:
const Main = ({ username }) =>{

return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>
          Hey, {username}
        </h1>
</div>
    </>
  );
};

i am accessing the prop in main and home page, but i am getting undefined. I tried to log the value of username in console and its showing the username properly.
Any kind of suggestions will be grateful.

At the moment I can see only two things that can go wrong, 1st being that the conditions if (response.ok ) never evaluates to true because ok prop does not excist, check the console for that. 2nd one is that data.username is undefined, can you try just setusername(data) and in your <Home /> and  <Main /> try to accesses it there?

@mssp thanks for the help, response.ok evaluates to true if the status is 200-299. And as you said to try setusername(data), it is not working. Actually its the same thing, either if i set the data or data.username

Share the code for your Main/Home component as well. I don't see any issues in what you have posted now

@nullptr Thanks for the response. I have updated the above code with main component

Just to clarify so in Home the username is working fine but in Main it is not?

@ChristianM No, in both the components it is not working. I just gave the Main component's code here. Home component's code is similar to Main, just with some add ons.

Is it showing as undefined or null? because if it's undefined, data.username probably doesn't exist.

@nullptr it's showing undefined. data.username exists and it is properly logged in console. I used console.log(username) in the Main component, and its showing the value at first but when i am navigating to that page, its again changing to undefined.

Provide a [mre], there is not issue that I can see in your code
